# SyntaxError invalid syntax

Tags: python

what error with this code:

```
data = ['K:C:192.168.1.3:myusername:mypassword', 'M:N:192.168.3.2:root:toor']
for i in data:
        r = str(i).strip(":")
        if len(r) == 4:
            print r[0] + "   ||" + ((28 - len(r[1])) / 2) * " " + r[1] + ((28 - len(r[1]) / 2) * " " + "||" + ((22 - len(r[2])) / 2) * " " + r[2] + ((22 - len(r[2])) / 2) * ' ' + "||" + ((22 - len(r[3])) / 2) * " " + r[3] + ((22 - len(r[3])) / 2) * " "
        elif len(r) == 3:
            print r[0] + "   ||" + ((28 - len(r[1])) / 2) * " " + r[1] + ((28 - len(r[1]) / 2) * " " + "||" + ((22 - len(r[2])) / 2) * " " + r[2] + ((22 - len(r[2])) / 2) * ' ' + "||"
```

a got an error like this:

```
    elif len(r) == 3:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please unify quotation marks!

Comment: You don't need to add spaces yourself that way -- you can just tell the format string to pad things out for you. Look at how `%28s` works, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a simple case of mismatched parentheses on the preceding line (and also on the following line).  Try this:

```
data = ['K:C:192.168.1.3:myusername:mypassword', 'M:N:192.168.3.2:root:toor']
for i in data:
    r = str(i).strip(":")
    if len(r) == 4:
        print r[0] + "   ||" + ((28 - len(r[1])) / 2) * " " + r[1] + ((28 - len(r[1])) / 2) * " " + "||" + ((22 - len(r[2])) / 2) * " " + r[2] + ((22 - len(r[2])) / 2) * ' ' + "||" + ((22 - len(r[3])) / 2) * " " + r[3] + ((22 - len(r[3])) / 2) * " "
    elif len(r) == 3:
        print r[0] + "   ||" + ((28 - len(r[1])) / 2) * " " + r[1] + ((28 - len(r[1])) / 2) * " " + "||" + ((22 - len(r[2])) / 2) * " " + r[2] + ((22 - len(r[2])) / 2) * ' ' + "||"
```

Comment: thanks tom, it works

Comment: Also, I **strongly** suggest you invest in a text editor that performs automatic braces completion for you. [Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com/3) is my favorite, but there are many available.